# Graphviz enforce edge start and stop position

Tags: graphviz

I have a GraphViz directed graph, that looks in a simplified version like this

```
digraph g {
  rankdir=LR
  node [shape=record]

  subgraph "cluster_R" {
    label="R"
    "R_in" [label="in|<in_0> 0"]
    "R_out" [label="out|<out_0> 0"]
  }
  "R_in" -> "R_out" [style=invis]

  subgraph "cluster_D" {
    label="D"
    "D_in" [label="in|<in_0> 0"]
    "D_out" [label="out|<out_0> 0|<out_1> 1"]
  }
  "D_in" -> "D_out" [style=invis]

  subgraph "cluster_P" {
    label="P"
    "P_in" [label="in|<in_0> 0|<in_1> 1"]
    "P_out" [label="out|<out_0> 0"]
  }
  "P_in" -> "P_out" [style=invis]


  "R_out":"out_0" -> "D_in":"in_0"  [weight=10]
  "P_out":"out_0" -> "R_in":"in_0" [weight=10]
  "D_out":"out_0" -> "P_in":"in_0"
}
```

This renders OK ([see](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/?compressed=CYSw5gTghgDgFgAjAg3gKAQ6A7A1qCAXgBkAlDBbAe2AFMEBtAZzllsIloGMqJgBdNBSYBXAEaRYiAERcANiKYAXWhAD6paagqY5UMbTmFpmnQhNqQ2LQz0Gj0qwB8APFbUAGAHwIP0wZiYFlQiSjZ2hsYhSq7Rnj5%2BAQgAvhQWVloAtD7BoTbKAJ5y7FYAbiBMgsLikvDm8ooq6gAiWuiBCBEOrWbSzZbWjF3Gzm7Y8b7%2Bvf3R4fqR0tGxoRMey0pqAIw%2Bm1OYqUH9GQjZ5jN5jIXFhGUVVZiiEtB1sgrKqmoACm1mw9LfvU%2BAzm9hG2Fc7m8vgh422CF2SSCQNmQ3mDiWLjiUMSFAO5iBx1O-zUKOYSiKJWw5UqQjSpBJeQAXIsVn4TjkjtZmZCtIwAO60cBwJSETYeJLE2bMrFZHL0jLc8ZshgCoUisUS85haWs2X44GKzzSNDJIA)) but I would like to start the unweighted edge at the right side of the source node and end at the left side of the destination node. So I modified the last edge like this

```
  "D_out":"out_0":e -> "P_in":"in_0":w
```

Now the edge starts end ends at the right place but takes an extra route at the edge of the enclosing nodes `D_out` and `P_in`. How can I prevent that and make a smooth edge that goes all around the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to get Graphviz to re-think its edges, but today we're lucky.  Unfortunately it took a total rewrite of the nodes, changing them from **record** to **HTML**, to allow adding invisible cells.  This in-turn "convinced" Graphviz to draw the edge below the nodes.  Whew.
But a nice looking result.

```
digraph g {
  rankdir=LR
  //node [shape=record]

  subgraph "cluster_R" {
    label="R"
    R [shape=none label=<<table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
    <tr><td style="invis" width="55"></td>    <td style="invis" width="34"></td> <td style="invis" width="55"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>in</td>     <td style="invis"></td> <td>out</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="in_0">0</td> <td style="invis"></td> <td port="out_0">0</td></tr>
    </table>>]
  }

  subgraph "cluster_D" {
    label="D"
    D [shape=none label=<<table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
    <tr><td style="invis" width="55"></td>  <td style="invis" width="34"></td> <td style="invis" width="55"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>in</td>            <td style="invis" ></td> <td>out</td></tr>    
    <tr><td port="in_0">0</td> <td style="invis" ></td> <td port="out_0">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="invis"></td> <td style="invis" ></td> <td>1</td></tr>
    </table>>]
  }
 
  subgraph "cluster_P" {
    label="P"
    P [shape=none label=<<table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
    <tr><td style="invis" width="55"></td>   <td style="invis" width="34"></td> <td style="invis" width="55"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>in</td>            <td style="invis" ></td> <td>out</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="in_0">0</td> <td style="invis" ></td> <td port="out_0">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td port="in_1">1</td> <td style="invis" ></td> </tr>
    </table>>]
  }

   R:"out_0" -> D:"in_0"  [weight=10]
   P:"out_0" -> R:"in_0"  [weight=10]
   P:"in_0":w  ->  D:"out_0":e [dir=back] // this makes all the difference!
 }
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Wow. What a whole lot of code to make this work. Thanks a lot.